# Looking for Free & Light web server for WinCE

Tags: webserver, windows-ce

I want to find free and light Web Server for WinCE.

The best of variants is I really want to find light and free ASP.NET web Server.

Or maybe if I can use Web Frameworks for Python or Ruby (maybe Ruby on Rails) or maybe I even can run something alike haskell web server (but I don't really believe it).

I don't like PHP (maybe religious reasons) but if that is the only variant of hosted web application on WinCE I would like to know if there any web server for it.

Thank you.

Comment: You are aware that Windows CE has an HTTPD server available right out of the box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Padarn](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/Padarn/tabid/267/Default.aspx) is a light ASP.NET web server for WinCE, but it is not free.
 
You could also try cross-compiling Apache with [CeGCC](http://cegcc.sourceforge.net/) for example, since cygwin and mingw do not support WinCE.

Another non-free option could be [Pocket HPH](http://mobileleap.net/hph/) (compact PHP processing engine designed to run on handheld devices), although it looks old and abandoned.

Comment: but Padarn isn't free - right ?

Comment: It's not, I stated that in my answer. I think you will not be able to find anything free that satisfies your requirements.By the way, I am assuming you do not want to use the http server provided with Windows CE (see ctacke comments above).

Comment: I'm able to use http server provided with Windows CE :) I just opened it for myself.