# Possible to run "WAMP" on Windows CE, WM8650 netbook?

Tags: php, mysql, windows-ce, wamp

Does any one know of a "WAMP" type of setup for running PHP and an SQL of some sort on the mini 7" WM8650 WonderMedia netbook?

I know, this is an odd question, but what it comes down to, is that I have a couple of these, and need some technicians in the field, have access to a web based form. I am simply wanting to create a local version of this form for these netbooks, so that I do not have to connect them to the internet while in the field.

I am currently running Windows CE 6.0 on the netbook, and figured wamp would just install. But of course everything has to be complicated. I have dome some searches, and originally I saw a youtube video showing wamp being installed on one of these devices, but ofcourse no link to anything on the comments and I honestly cant find the video now...

Anyway, if any one knows how I can do this, please let me know. I am told this thing can run debian as well, but I am not familiar with debian enough to use it, let alone know how to set it up with something like wamp. If someone can tell me if this would be a better way to go, let me know, and please provide some link or instruction on how I can setup a simple local "php server" on either windows ce, or debian (or even android)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038459/looking-for-free-light-web-server-for-wince/7040414#7040414

Comment: I have seen this other one, but I am needing a free option, and have looked at how to get WinCE to use its own web server but have not figured it out :/

Answer (score 0):

Try use a portable version of WampServer, or better XAMPP.
Portable versions no need install, it can run directly from a stick, so, I think it works on notebook too.
Try look on the net for: " portable xampp " to find the application to download.

Comment: This will not work. Portable versions of WAMP are designed for the desktop versions of Windows (aka XP, Vista, Win7, etc). Here the OP is talking about WiNCE, this is a different beast.

Answer (score 0):

For the scenario using Windows CE:

If you are the manufacturer of the target device, you need to include ASP web server support on your WinCE OS image. If you are not the manufacturer of your device, then you need to contact them and request them to include ASP web server support on the OS image (though it might not be possible for them).

Another possible approach would be to implement your own web server in C# based on .Net Compact Framework, you can use this sample project from MSDN as starting point:

[.NET Compact Framework Sample: Mobile Web Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22794)

You mentioned that you just one to show some HTML forms locally on the device, so this sample project might be enough for your needs.